Скажите — старый знакомый. Скажите: старый знакомый. Как правильно?
Скажите — старый знакомый. Скажите: старый знакомый. Как правильно? "Старый знакомый" надо писать со строчной буквы?
В первом случае можно предположить, что пропущено "что".
У А. Пушкина есть такие строки:
Скажи: есть память обо мне,
Есть в мире сердце, где живу я...

Полное выражение еще могло бы выглядеть так: Скажите, что это его старый знакомый.

Склоняюсь оформить как прямую речь. Скажите: "Старый знакомый".  Двоеточие после "скажите", но далее без кавычек я вижу часто. Но там другой смысл. Вот, к примеру, идешь ты в бой и думаешь: «Иду я за родную землю». Так вот ты и скажи: за что же ты идешь? К. Паустовский, Бакенщик. Скажи: есть память обо мне,
Есть в мире сердце, где живу я... А. Пушкин

Еще добавлю.  Я это предложение сначала представила в таком виде: "Скажете – старый знакомый".  Здесь тире подходит идеально. А вот вариант "Скажите – старый знакомый"  допускает уже оба знака. Тоже примерила двоеточие, но все-таки выбрала тире для динамичности речи.  Но двоеточие тоже подойдет, это уже по тексту надо смотреть.  Все это можно проверить по произношению.

Правильно: Скажите — старый знакомый.
Пояснение

Это БСП, отношения изъяснительные, лучше обозначить тире. Это дословное высказывание, и здесь возможны варианты оформления.

Прямая речь по обычным правилам не подойдет, так как высказывание нераспространенное.

Двоеточие тоже не стоит использовать по той же причине.  Для сравнения: у  Пушкина распространенная изъяснительная часть.


Также двоеточие ставится при увеличенной паузе (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю), а здесь не такая большая пауза. Но как вариант двоеточие возможно, это авторский выбор по контексту (какое произношение больше подойдет).

Склоняюсь оформить как прямую речь. Скажите: «Старый знакомый». Думаете, будет ошибкой?

Ошибкой не будет, это авторский выбор. Но такой вариант не кажется обоснованным. Это еще контекст надо смотреть, ведь предложение должно вписаться  в общий текст.   Такое впечатление, что события там развиваются динамично,  и  форма предложения должна соответствовать. Если хотите сделать паузу, то выберите лучше двоеточие.

Спасибо большое за помощь!
